# How can I secure socket.io upon XSS attacks?

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, socket.io

I have implemented a REST project with httpOnly cookie token authentication to prevent XSS attacks.
I've added chat system by socket.io, wondering how can I secure it upon XSS attacks.
As you know in XSS attack, hacker steals user's token and pretends to be him/her.
In socket.io, the client has access to the auth, how can we protect it from the attacker?

```
const socket = io({
  auth: {
    token: "abc"
  }
});
```

Comment: "As you know in XSS attack, hacker steals user's token and pretends to be him/her." — While that is often the **goal** of an XSS attack, the attack itself involves the injection of JavaScript into a page on someone else's browser. How you deal with XSS attacks depends on correctly handling user input, not on the transport mechanism itself.